# What are the roles of these two in's in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, subjects

I encountered [a strange expression](https://openintro-ims.netlify.app/data-hello.html) as follows:

> These two summary statistics are useful **in** looking for differences in the groups, and we are **in** for a surprise: an additional 8% of patients in the treatment group had a stroke!

It seems that I have never seen the preposition 'in' being used in a way like the two in's bolded in the above quote.

What's more, I cannot comprehend the 'looking for' after the first 'in' because I don't know what its subject is. Is the subject 'we' mentioned before the second 'in'?

What grammar rules am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Are useful in looking" can be paraphrased as "help us to look for differences". "In for a surprise" can be paraphrased as "It's certain that we will receive a surprise".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first *in* has the same function as the following simpler sentence, which I hope you can understand:

> These two summary statistics are useful *in* the following situation:

That sentence could be followed by "looking for differences in the groups", your quote simply omits the "the following situation".

The second *in* is an [adverb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in#h2-anchor) and part of the idiomatic expression *in for*:

> **in for**
> : certain to experience
> // *in for* a rude awakening

(source: Merriam-Webster)